# ElementTree Parsing error because of an apostrophe " ’ " (no XML declarations)

Tags: python, xml, encoding, elementtree

I am using ElementTree to look through MySQL records and parse out XML that is stored without any declarations. I know that there is something wrong with text encoding, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue. The error I'm getting is:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token):
```

I have tried s.decode("CP1252").encode("UTF-8") and a simple s.replace("’", "") but neither helped (where s is the record of XML). I also printed the string before and after these transformations, only to see that when printed, the character reads "?", before and after the transformations. I was expecting to see it disappear after the replace("'",""), but it did not.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

'
EDIT::

I was in the process of replicating the issue with a string vs. using MySqlDb but it wasn't producing an error. By default, MySQLDb is not UTF-8 encoded, so that must be specified in the DB connection. Once I added the 'init_command... ...utf8'  to the end of my connection, it was able to interpret the apostrophe and include it in the REPLACE(column_with_xml, "'", "") part of my query.

```
conn = MySQLdb.Connection(db=config.mydb['mydb'], host=config.mydb['host'], port=config.mydb['port'], user=config.mydb['user'], passwd=config.mydb['password'], init_command='SET NAMES utf8',charset='utf8')
```

Comment: could we maybe see the offending xml data?

Comment: It could well be special characters that XML cannot interprate. Try replace your "'" with "&apos;" (without quaotes). http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html

Comment: Offending xml data: <Device><Name>Joel’s iPhone</Name></Device>. Also - I don't have any control over the format of the XML name value. I can only make adjustments downstream.

Comment: Could you include the entire code you are trying? It would be nice to be able to reproduce the error in order to help you with your issue.

Comment: Please edit the question when you want to clarify it. Long chunks of code in comments are hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Added it to the question.

Comment: So did `init_command ...` fix it? Or do you still get the error?